# C#.Анимация с формой

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли при нажатии на "Esc" переместить плавно форму в верхний левый угол рабочего экрана? Это как перетащить мышью. Спасибо.

Comment: WinAPI вам в помощь

Comment: Ну хоть какие-то примеры или ссылки...

Comment: c WinAPI Все просто, ищем окно, получаем хендл, и шлем ему соотвествующие сообщения (как будто мы мышкой двигаем), Если надо плавно, значит это какой-либо таймер.

Comment: Хотя, у вс же есть координаты самой формы? Вот, поймав клавишу Esc, их и меняйте плавно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно реализовать с помощью события по нажатию клавиши. Примерно так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer t;
    public Form1()
    {
        t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 10;
        t.Tick += tick;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            deltaX = this.Left / 30;
            deltaY = this.Top / 30;
            t.Start();

        }
    }
    private void tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Left > 0 || this.Top > 0)
        {
            if (this.Left > 0) this.Left -= this.Left > deltaX ? deltaX : this.Left;
            if (this.Top > 0) this.Top -= this.Top > deltaY ? deltaY : this.Top;
        }
        else
        {
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Немного поправил. Теперь окно двигается ровно в угол. Скорость регулируется либо за счет t.Interval, либо за счет делителя при определении deltaX и deltaY, либо за счет того и другого. Не стоит интервал ставить слишком большим (будет видно как форма "шагает" по экрану).